# Engine.Razor.Run causes InvalidCastException

Tags: razor, razorengine

I have the following code to get my cshtml Email Template.

```
try
            {

            var layoutTemplateKey = new NameOnlyTemplateKey("layout", ResolveType.Global, null);
            if (!Engine.Razor.IsTemplateCached(layoutTemplateKey, null))
                Engine.Razor.AddTemplate(layoutTemplateKey, ReadTemplateFile("/Views/Email/Layout.cshtml"));

            var templateKey = new NameOnlyTemplateKey(templatePath, ResolveType.Global, null);
            if (!Engine.Razor.IsTemplateCached(templateKey, viewModel.GetType()))
            {
                Engine.Razor.AddTemplate(templateKey, ReadTemplateFile(templatePath));
                Engine.Razor.Compile(templateKey, viewModel.GetType());
            }

            return viewModel == null ?
                Engine.Razor.Run(templateKey) :
                Engine.Razor.Run(templateKey, viewModel.GetType(), viewModel);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
```

However My the Engine.Razor.Run causes `InvalidCastException` with a model which is no where referenced here.

And it continuously happens with any other models too.

The recent change I was done was inheriting each of this class by another Model to be used in the `Layout.cshtml`.

Expected Model: `NewBookRecievedEmailViewModel`

```
public class NewBookRecievedEmailViewModel : EmailHelperModel
    {
        public ProposalPostedEmailViewModel()
        {
            this.canBeDeleted = true;
        }

        public string BookName { get; set; }

        public string Author {get; set;}
    }
```

Gets error with Model PayOutBookEmailViewModel

```
public class PayOutBookEmailViewModel : EmailHelperModel
    {
        public string BookID { get; set; }

        public string BookUrl {get; set;}
    }
```

And the inherited Model is : EmailHelper

```
public class EmailHelperModel
    {
        public bool canBeDeleted { get; set;  }
        public string DeleteUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateBase`1.SetModel(Object model)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateBase.SetData(Object model, DynamicViewBag viewbag)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineCore.CreateTemplate(ICompiledTemplate template, Object model, DynamicViewBag viewbag)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineCoreWithCache.ResolveInternal(String cacheName, Object model, Type modelType, DynamicViewBag viewbag, ResolveType resolveType, ITemplateKey context)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.InternalTemplateService.Resolve(String name, Object model, Type modelType, DynamicViewBag viewbag, ResolveType resolveType)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateBase`1.ResolveLayout(String name)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateBase.RazorEngine.Templating.ITemplate.Run(ExecuteContext context, TextWriter reader)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineCore.RunTemplate(ICompiledTemplate template, TextWriter writer, Object model, DynamicViewBag viewBag)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineService.Run(ITemplateKey key, TextWriter writer, Type modelType, Object model, DynamicViewBag viewBag)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.DynamicWrapperService.Run(ITemplateKey key, TextWriter writer, Type modelType, Object model, DynamicViewBag viewBag)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineServiceExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<Run>b__0(TextWriter writer)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineServiceExtensions.WithWriter(Action`1 withWriter)
   at RazorEngine.Templating.RazorEngineServiceExtensions.Run(IRazorEngineService service, ITemplateKey key, Type modelType, Object model, DynamicViewBag viewBag)
   at Pxp.Api.Helpers.EmailHelper.GetHtmlContent(String templatePath, Object viewModel)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using cshtml, consider using actual HTML; or better yet, generating elements with JavaScript, it's the real way-to-go, here' some sample code of how to create an element in JavaScript:

```
var MyEngine = new (function() {
     this.el = function(opts) {
        if(!svgList.split(" ").find(x => x == opts.tag)) {
            this.node = document.createElement(opts.tag || "div");
        } else {
            this.node = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', opts.tag);
        } 

        for(var k in opts) {
            if(k == "style") {
                for(var s in opts[k]) {
                    this.node.style[s] = opts[k][s];
                }
            } else if(k != "parent"){
                this.node[k] = opts[k];
            }
        }



        this.setAttrs = (attrs) => {
            for(var k in attrs) {
                this.node.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
            }
        };
        this.getAttr = (at) => {
            return this.node.getAttribute(at);
        };

        this.setStyle = (stl) => {
            for(var k in stl) {
                this.node.style[k] = stl[k];
            }
        }

        var attr = opts.attr || {};
        this.setAttrs(attr);
        var optsPar = opts.parent;
        var par = null;
        if(optsPar) {
            if(optsPar.constructor == String) {
                par = f("#" + optsPar);
            } else if(optsPar instanceof Element) {
                par = optsPar;
            }
        }

        this.parent = par || document.body || {appendChild: (d) => {}};
        this.parent.appendChild(this.node);
     };
)();
```

then to create a new element:

```
var temp = new MyEngine.el({
    id:"hi",
    style:{position:absolute, left:100+"px"},
    innerHTML:"<b>nice to meet you</b>
});
```

Comment: That is a nice Suggestion By The Way.